# Selenium - for-loop in not giving all results while looping through list of elements

Tags: python, function, selenium, for-loop, web-scraping

I'm having an issue while looping through `products` and calling function `get_prod_details`. The needed output is

```
{
  'name of products': [{
    'title': 'Vegetable Basket'
  }, {
    'title': 'Russian Nesting Dolls'
  }, {
    'title': 'Fish Painting'
  }, {
    'title': 'Dead Parrot'
  }, {
    'title': 'Mystery Box'
  }]
}
```

but instead of that I get

```
{
  'name of products': [{
    'title': 'Vegetable Basket'
  }, {
    'title': 'Vegetable Basket'
  }, {
    'title': 'Vegetable Basket'
  }, {
    'title': 'Vegetable Basket'
  }, {
    'title': 'Vegetable Basket'
  }]
}
```

I can't understand why it loops through the first element multiple times, and not go through the next elements.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
url = "http://pythonscraping.com/pages/page3.html"

driver.get(url)

prod_list = []


def run():
    get_data()
    end_result()

def get_data():    
    products = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class, "gift")]')
    for product in products:
        get_prod_details(product)

def get_prod_details(product):
    prod_dict= {}
    tittle = product.find_element_by_xpath('//td[1]').text
    prod_dict['title'] = tittle

    prod_list.append(prod_dict)

def end_result():
    print({
        'name of products': prod_list
    })

print(run())
```

Answer (score 0):

### What happens?

It is in your `get_prod_details` - `//` Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are. So it selects every iteration the same

```
product.find_element_by_xpath('//td[1]').text
```

### Solution

Prepend a `.` to select the current node:

```
tittle = product.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[1]').text
```

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
url = "http://pythonscraping.com/pages/page3.html"

driver.get(url)

prod_list = []


def run():
    get_data()
    end_result()

def get_data():    
    products = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class, "gift")]')
    for product in products:
        get_prod_details(product)

def get_prod_details(product):
    prod_dict= {}
    tittle = product.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[1]').text
    prod_dict['title'] = tittle

    prod_list.append(prod_dict)

def end_result():
    print({
        'name of products': prod_list
    })

run()
driver.close()
```

**Output**

```
{'name of products': [{'title': 'Vegetable Basket'}, {'title': 'Russian Nesting Dolls'}, {'title': 'Fish Painting'}, {'title': 'Dead Parrot'}, {'title': 'Mystery Box'}]}
```